# How to get text which excludes the html from a table's cell in Datatables

Tags: datatables

I am trying to get the value of a cell.  I am using this code:

```
    var table = $('#table-list-users').DataTable();
    $('#table-list-users tbody').on('click', 'td', function(){
        someValue = table.cell( this ).data() ; 
        console.log(someValue);
    })
```

Some of my cells contain html so when I click on a cell, I get 8032456953 instead of just 8032456953.  How can I get just the text?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see any specific method in DataTables so am just using:

```
    currow = $(this).closest('tr');
    someValueTwo = currow.find('td:eq(3)').text();
```